# Find Value in Table and Return Column Header In Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following table in Excel

[image]

According to the color of cell G2, what formula should I write in cell H2 to get the answer?
for example
G2 = Red
H2 = Group3
If the color is not in the table, the formula will return NotFind
I did not get the answer with VLOOKUP or index match
The match function works on a one-dimensional array
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `CONCAT()` & `REPT()`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `H2`

```
=CONCAT(REPT(A1:E1,N(G2=A2:E5)))
```

---

Using `INDEX()` & `AGGREGATE()`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `H2`

```
=IFERROR(
    INDEX(
        $A$1:$E$1,
        AGGREGATE(
            15,
            6,
            COLUMN($A$1:$E$1) /
                (
                    G2 =
                        $A$2:$E$5
                ),
            1
        )
    ),
    "Not Found"
)
```

---

Or,

Using `INDEX()` & `MAX()`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `H2`

```
=INDEX($A$1:$E$1,MAX(N(G2=$A$2:$E$5)*COLUMN($A$1:$E$1)))
```

---

Or,

Using only `AGGREGATE()`

[image]

---

```
="Group"&AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN($A$1:$E$1)/($A$2:$E$5=G2),1)
```

---

Comment: For `M365`, `=FILTER(A1:E1,BYCOL(A2:E5=G2,LAMBDA(x,OR(x))))`.

Comment: Wow --> **5x Alternatives**